# xamarin forms what is the difference content page and content view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

What is the difference between:

- content page
- contentpage.content
- content view ?

What I'm trying to do is to have some content that overlays the main content when an item is being tapped. I was thinking I could have all the content on in the same XMAL file and just make it visible or not depending on the button state. Or would it be better to split them into separate files?

Answer (score 57):

A `ContentPage` is a `Page` that is intended to fill the display.  A `ContentView` is a `View` that can be contained within a `Page` or within another `View`.  Both have a `Content` property that contains child content - either a single `View`, or more commonly a `Layout` containing multiple `Views`.

Comment: ok, thanks you. so if i could i have a content page with a stack layout inside of it. That contains two content views could i use the stacklayout.RaiseChild(contentview) to show the content ? if so is this good practice ?

Comment: I don't think RaiseChild will help you.  If you want drag-drop functionality there are samples out there of how to achieve this.  If you want content to overlap I'd look at either Absolute or Relative layouts and adjust their position to achieve the result you want.

Comment: thanks you i will take a look into them. what would you use RaseChild() for ?

Answer (score 0):

I like using grid. You can mix both proportional and absolute values, and you can span rows and columns if you need to. I just wrote an app that looks good on both windows and Android form factors. By using grid I can change the size of the windows app window and everything stays looking nice. Also use grid to generate a scroll view within a small view inside the window.