# Differences between ContentPage and ContentView

Tags: xamarin.forms

What is the difference between ContentPage and ContentView? Visual Studio are creating new classes inherited from ContentView (until recently it generated new classes inherited from ContentPage).

For example, the prior version of Visual Studio generated:

```
public partial class MyContentPage : ContentPage{... }
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XamarinPagesApp.Views.MyContentPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The new version is now generating:

```
   public partial class MyContentPage : ContentView{... }
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XamarinPagesApp.Views.MyContentPage">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />
      </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Why does the code generator behave this way now? What is the difference between contentPage and contentView?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xamarin forms what is the difference content page and content view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969241/xamarin-forms-what-is-the-difference-content-page-and-content-view)

Comment: yes, @MihailDuchev, it does. I'm actually curious to know why they started using ContentView instead of ContentPage. but I'm not sure if I will have an answer on that. anyway thank you very much for your attention