# Xamarin.Forms pages, views and viewmodels

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I’m quite new to mobile development.
What is the difference between page and view?
From what I understand a page is a container of views, which in turn, if the MVVM pattern is implemented can have an associated ViewModel.
In this scenario, the page does not have an associated ViewModel.
Is it right?
Thanks

Comment: Yes and no. Every page and every view can have their own ViewModel attached. ViewModels contain the business logic of an app, so the main functionality which should be agnostic of any Pages and Views. A page is, like the name says, a page that usually fills the screen. Views usually exist within pages or other Views and hold controls, labels, etc. They're not interchangeable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48969241/xamarin-forms-what-is-the-difference-content-page-and-content-view

Comment: Docs: [Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/pages), [Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/views).  Note: **A page is a type of view.**. Therefore, if you are doing MVVM-style coding your pages will have ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page is used when creating different screens (pages), such as LoginPage. View is a UI interface that can be embedded in a page. In MVVM, the view is notified when the properties of the view model change. Both page and view can be data bound.

For more information about MVVM, you can refer to: [The Model-View-ViewModel Pattern | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm)

Comment: So, as @ewerspej said, the ViewModel of a page, for example, can contain the logic to enable the continue button only if the views that make it up have met certain conditions. Is it right? (In this scenario, ViewModels of the views will notify the ViewModel of the page)